# Can't Click On Controls After Adding Css

Tags: html, css

I've added a new css element to my master page. But After that, I can't click on other controls in the page. I know some div is overlapping the other making click not working. But I couldn't figure it out with the css file. My css file is given below:

here where I placed my div in html :

```css
/* XLSF 2007 */

body {
  background: #333 url(image/bg-strip-dark.png) 0px 0px;
  font-family: normal, "Century Gothic", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", georgia, "times new roman", "Arial Rounded MT Bold", helvetica, verdana, tahoma, arial, "sans serif";
  font-size: 75%;
  color: #666;
}
h1,
h1 a {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
}
h1 {
  color: #999;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
h1,
h2,
h3 {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  font-family: normal, "Century Gothic", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica Neue", georgia, "times new roman", "Arial Rounded MT Bold", helvetica, verdana, tahoma, arial, "sans serif";
  font-size: 3em;
  font-size-adjust: none;
  margin-bottom: 0.25em;
  padding-bottom: 1px;
}
h1,
h2 {
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
a {
  color: #6699cc;
  padding: 0px 2px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  background: #6699cc;
  color: #fff;
}
#lights {
  clear: both;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 96px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 1;
}
.xlsf-light {
  position: relative;
}
body.fast .xlsf-light {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
.xlsf-fragment {
  position: relative;
  background: transparent url(image/bulbs-50x50-fragments.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.xlsf-fragment-box {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  *width: 100%;
  *height: 100%;
  display: none;
}
.xlsf-cover {
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  opacity: 1;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
}
/*
.xlsf-light.bottom {
 height:49px;
 border-bottom:1px solid #006600;
}

.xlsf-light.top {
 height:49px;
 border-top:1px solid #009900;
}
*/
```

```html
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="MasterPage.master.cs" Inherits="MasterPage" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="christmaslights.css" />
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    <style type="text/css">
      .style1 {
        width: 135px;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="snowstorm.js"></script>
    <script>
      snowStorm.snowColor = '#99ccff'; // blue-ish snow!?
      snowStorm.flakesMaxActive = 96; // show more snow on screen at once
      snowStorm.useTwinkleEffect = true; // let the snow flicker in and out of view
    </script>
    <script src="lights/soundmanager2-nodebug-jsmin.js"></script>
    <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/combo?2.6.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js&2.6.0/build/animation/animation-min.js"></script>
    <script src="lights/christmaslights.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <div>
        <table style="width:100%;">
          <tr>
            <td class="style1">
              <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/remedyonline-logo.png" />
            </td>
            <td>
              <span style="font-family: Tahoma; font-size: xx-large; font-weight: bold; color: #666666; padding-left: 10px;">Representatives Corner
                    
                    <marquee direction="right"><font color=#993300 size=5 ><strong>GDS Wishes A HAPPY X'MAS</strong></marquee></font>
                   
                    </span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="lights">
    </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

At least please notify me where's the problem. I am new to html and css.

Comment: Show your html too, if you can in a fiddle

Comment: i have added my html also.but wherever i place that div i cant click anywhere in the page.but after removing it it works fine.

Comment: show us full html in the fiddle. I think ur `<head>` tag is not well maintained here

Comment: full html and css added for your reference.can you help me to figure it out?

Comment: guys i made it working.the https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector tools really helped me to figure it out where the actual problem lies.anyway thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that one of the elements with a modified `z-index` property is rendered above the aforementioned controls. The solution, then, would be to isolate which one of them is problematic for you by removing the properties and observing the results.

A better solution, however, might be to learn about the developer tools in your favorite browser - they can be incredibly helpful for situations like this:

[Chrome Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

[Firefox Dev Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Page_Inspector)

Comment: Thanks.it was a nice suggestion .when i used firefox developer tools i got to know where the actual problem is.